# Wordpress database import: Row size too large

Tags: database, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I've done a dump of my Wordpress database using Windows's command prompt:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > filename.sql
```

Then, on a different server, imported it using:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql
```

I get this error when importing the values column in the wordpress_options table:

```
#1118 - Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

The weird thing is, both the original and new databases are using 'longtext' for this column, which I believe can store 4GB of data.  My options value column is only 1.9MB!

I'm wondering if it is a setting in mysql? I've set the maximum packet size to 16MB and the key buffer size to 32MB

**EDIT**
Here is the SQL that creates the WordPress options table

```
--
-- Table structure for table `wordpress_options`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wordpress_options`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `wordpress_options` (
  `option_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `option_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `option_value` longtext NOT NULL,
  `autoload` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4872 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I've also tried using phpMyAdmin for the import, instead of the command line, but the result is the same.

Comment: probably a mysql question, but I am going to guess that your DBs don't have the same structure

Comment: Hi @MarkKaplun I've added the SQL that creates the table if that helps.

Comment: As I said, this is a mysql question not a wordpress one. I have no real idea even what to look for.

Comment: Check the innodb_log_file_size in the mySQL instance.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637733/mysql-error-code-1118-row-size-too-large-8126-changing-some-columns-to-te

Comment: Thanks @Otto you're a life-saver! I'm using MySQL 5.6.20 so that was indeed the problem. Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: I did add it as an answer. SE must have converted it to a comment. :)

Comment: The swines! Haha. Maybe post it again as an answer? I could answer my own question, but I'd like you to gain the reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs in MySQL 5.6.20 or later, if the innodb_log_file_size in the my.ini is set too low. I changed mine to 16M and the problem went away.
Thanks to @Otto for the solution.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-20.html